# Make a loop inside NodeJS Web server?

Tags: node.js, loops, express

I'm doing a big project in NodeJS using Express and I wonder if I can make an infinite loop inside the server application. I think this cannot be accomplished in other languages such as Java (because it would stall the application) but I'm not sure about the JS behavior in this case.

The server application has to do two main tasks. The first one is to handle the web page (it has to listen for requests and stuff like that). The second one would be looping through a cluster  of arduinos via wifi in order to get some values. These values would be sent to the web page using socket.io.

So, the question is: is it possible for the server to do two tasks at the same time? I imagine the requests sent from the web page to the server as events that would stop the loop iteration, and once they are answered the loop continues.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Express works as a middleware,  answering REST calls. The loop as you want may be feasible using others packages, like CRON or NODE-SCHEDULE. Another possible way could be to implement a setInterval()

Comment: Thanks I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your server to handle the webpage, and use a `cronjob` to trigger a function which queries the arduinos.

There are npm packages that enable you to define `cronjobs` in your javascript code. One example of these is [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try this approach!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to start and stop the loop.

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => console.log('loop'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 100000);
```

Other approach (here you may dynamically change the interval if you like):

```js
let counter = 0;
const task = () => {
  console.log('loop');
  counter++;
  setTimeout(() => counter < 10? task() : void 0, 1000);
};
task();
```